# I believe I may have identified the very first instance of an anti PSE conspiracy (not bots)

Tags: discussion

All I get on my Facebook feed is entirely fabricated quotes, now. Nietzsche, Marcus Aurelius, Socrates, etc. (I'm still waiting for Rochefoucauld, but then aren't we all...)

It's a real industry. I don't know how people are making money from it or more to the point why people are making money from it, cos anything that real is not copyrighted. But you have Facebook memes, pages, people sharing the quote in the goodbooks site, books - entire books - of fabricated quotes.

It is inarguable that this is not an attempt to feed slop to the pigs. But:

- are they trying to undermine Stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I don't see how this has anything to do with StackExchange as such. There is a long-standing tradition of misattributed or misquoted "Quotes" finding their way into books and even idiomatic language.

Thus, this is rather a reflection of the algorithm attributing an interest for philosophy to you and mistaking these quotes 90% of people *think* are actual philosophy or philosophical as actual philosophy.

Comment: it's a new phase in big data. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Bear with me here. What's better than clicks?

- NOTHING IS BETTER THAN CLICKS

> What about clicks that look inside your soul?

- YOU ! But why not REAL quotes?

> Trickier to generate, and more easily thought about by the target

- Ok ! So that's all?

> Yes, but now we can trigger - some of you - you into shopping.

- The advertising jingle is watching you...